# Encrypt pdf file in python and decrypt that pdf file in java with AES_GCM mode

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

My problem is, I am not able to decrypt the pdf file in Java correctly with aes gcm mode. Despite using the correct key and IV, I am still getting error in decryption.

Python Encryption Code -

```py
def encrypt(in_file, out_file, password, key_length=32):
   
    bs = AES.block_size
   
  
    cipher = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_GCM, password )
    
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk = in_file.read(1024 * bs)
        if len(chunk) == 0 or len(chunk) % bs != 0:
            padding_length = (bs - len(chunk) % bs) or bs
            # changed right side to str.encode(...)
            chunk += str.encode(
                padding_length * chr(padding_length))
            finished = True
        out_file.write(cipher.encrypt(chunk))
```

Java Decryption Code-

```java
public static void decryptWithEcb(String filenameEnc, String filenameDec, byte[] key) throws Exception
            {
               
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filenameEnc);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filenameDec)) {
            byte[] ibuf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, key);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec ,gcmParameterSpec);
            while ((len = in.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
                byte[] obuf = cipher.update(ibuf, 0, len);
                if (obuf != null)
                    out.write(obuf);
            }
            byte[] obuf = cipher.doFinal();
            if (obuf != null)
                out.write(obuf);


        }
        
    }
}
```

Error coming in java-

```
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:620)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2051)
    at Encrypt.decryptWithEcb(Encrypt.java:72)
    at Encrypt.main(Encrypt.java:15)
```

Comment: Just a note - using the key as IV is not really a secure idea (reusing the same key and IV in GCM leads to a catastrophic failure). Questions: are you sure the "password" in the python code corresponds to the `byte[] key` ? Java implementation automatically assumes the GCM tag appended to the ciphertext (by default as the last 16 bytes). Is the tag written by the python code? In the python code I see the padding appended, in Java you asked for `NoPadding`

Comment: @gusto2 yes "password" in the python code corresponds to the byte[] key. i am calling It as ``` encrypt(open("check.pdf" , 'rb') ,open("check_enc.pdf" , 'wb') , str.encode('a1ebee1c0494785b'))```

Comment: Then you have to fix "just" the rest (IV, padding, auth tag)

Comment: @gusto2 in which code python or java

Comment: IV for both, padding and tag in python. I'm no good in python, so I'm unable to help with details.

Comment: Your python code is doing its own padding. Since you are using GCM mode, don't do that. Don't do any padding at all. Also, you must retrieve the authentication tag in the python code by calling `cipher.digest()`. It's easiest just to read the entire file into a bytes object and then call `cipher.encrypt_and_digest()`. There are examples of this in the documentation.